# Any place to speak with people in online in spanish?

Tags: conversación

I am new to Spanish language . I was using an app to learn Spanish but in that there is no chance to speak with people. I would like to know a place where I can practice with real people.

Comment: Welcome to [Spanish.SE]! This question is not about the Spanish language, but about _how_ to learn Spanish. This question is thus offtopic here, but you can try asking in the [Language Learning](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/) stack, or check out our [Resources for learning Spanish](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2514/12637) post in the Meta site.

Comment: This stack has a [chat room: La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia). It is not "face to face" talking, but I thought it was worth pointing it out, in case that you want to visit it.

Comment: Nominating to reopen.  We might not know the answer, but that doesn't make it a bad question, in my opinion.

Comment: @aparente001, I'm afraid this question falls under the "asking for learning resources" category. We could suggest many different online sites for conversation, places or ideas ("Use skype and chat with people from Spain; go where people who speak Spanish gather and talk to someone; Find a privater tutor"...). All equally valid (or not, depending on some context we haven't been given). I think this person should visit [La tertulia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46061/la-tertulia) and ask for/be given some ideas, but this question is not really suitable for the _stacks_ format.